# Difference between string and list and usuage of join

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to understand why and how python treats below example as string when it is actually a list. Does join(expression) treats expression as string?

EXAMPLE 1

```
available_letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
                     'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
                     's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

print 'Available letters: ' + ''.join(available_letters)
```

When I check type of  `' '.join(available_letters)` ,it has type string.
But if I use

```
print 'Available letters: ' + available_letters
```

then I get error cannot concatenate a string and a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the reason:

```
>>> available_letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
                         'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
                         's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

>>> x = ' '.join(available_letters)
>>> available_letters
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
>>> x
'a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z'

>>> type(available_letters)
<type 'list'>

>>> type(x)
<type 'str'>
```

As you see above, the `availabe_letters` is a variable of `list` type itself. But when you call `' '.join` method on it, its output is a string. concatenating of `list` and `str` is not correct, but concatenating of `str`s is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Python3:

```
available_letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
                     'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
                     's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

print ('Available letters: ', ''.join(available_letters))
```

Comment: Do not post  only code. Explain also your solution.